# Securing API keys in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, api-key

I've researched and found three different possibilities to solving my case: I'd like to make an async API call (using dotenv variables to store the credentials) and commit the returned data to Vuex on app init --keeping the creds secure.

1. Currently I'm attempting using serverMiddleware, but I'm having trouble accessing the context. Is this possible? Currently just getting a "store is not defined" error.
2. Also, after researching, I keep seeing that it's not a good idea to use regular middleware, as running any code on the client-side exposes the env variable... But I'm confused. Doesn't `if (!process.client) { ... }` take care of this? Or am I missing the bigger picture.
3. Additionally, if it *does turn out* to be okay to use middleware to secure the credentials, would using the [separate-env-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/separate-env-module) be wise to make doubly sure that nothing gets leaked client-side?

Thanks, I'm looking forward to understanding this more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `serverMiddleware`.

You can do it like this:

client -> call serverMiddleware -> servermiddleware calls API.

that way API key is not in client but remains on the server.

---

Example:

remote api is: `https://maps.google.com/api/something`

your api: `https://awesome.herokuapp.com`

since your own api has access to environment variables and you **don't** want the api key to be included in the generated client-side build, you create a `serverMiddleware` that will proxy the request for you.

So that in the end, your client will just make a call to `https://awesome.herokuapp.com/api/maps`, but that endpoint will just call `https://maps.google.com/api/something?apikey=123456` and return the response back to you

Comment: Can you please provide an example? I am dealing with this now